# Exception in Drawable.createFromResourceStream() -- HTC ONLY?

Tags: android, nine-patch, android-assets, htc-android

I've released an IME (soft keyboard) app and I am getting crash reports from **HTC phones only**. Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:465)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:666)
    at com.comet.android.keyboard.util.Util.getBitmapDrawable(MyFile.java:416)
    ...
```

Here is my call to Drawable.createFromResourceStream()

```
drawable = Drawable.createFromResourceStream(context.getResources(), null, stream, null);
```

where `context` a subclass of *InputMethodService* and `stream` either is a *FileInputStream* or *AssetInputStream* (I've tried both). The resource file is a compiled *NinePatchDrawable*. I've confirmed that stream is not null.

To repeat: **this bug only happens with certain HTC handsets** (including the Evo) running various versions of Android OS.

Has anyone experienced this and/or know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance,

Barry

P.S. What is strange is that crash line 465 is not within crash method *BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream()* in any version of *BitmapFactory.java* so HTC must be using modified code.

Comment: I am getting the same error. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution for this problem, you can replace the call to `Drawable.createFromResourceStream` with:

```
// set options to resize the image
Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inDensity = 160;

Drawable drawable  = null;
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), opts);
if (bm != null) {
  drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bm);
}
```

This only works with files.

Comment: Actually I need a solution that works with files instead of resources. However I'm using 9-patch PNGs which must be pre-compiled so I'm not sure this solution will work for me. I'll try it out and see...

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `Drawable.createFromStream ()` instead of `Drawable.createFromResourceStream()`

Comment: Can't, because he needs the opts.inDensity feature. Drawable.createFromStream () does not support android.graphics.Options.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried supplying `Drawable.createFromResourceStream` with a full set of valid params?
I've looked at the Android code, and you saftely pass both a dummy `TypedValue` and a dummy `Options` objects and still maintain the default behaviour.

So:

```
    Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    TypedValue dummy = new TypedValue(); 

    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromResourceStream( mContext.getResources(), dummy, in, assetPath, opts);
```

Can anyone verify this on an HTC device?

Comment: I can no longer reproduce this bug -- it is 2 years old -- so I can't test your fix. However I'm pretty sure I tried every variation of Drawable.create*() and they all failed. Ultimately they all reached line 465 of BitmapFactory.java and crashed.

Comment: For the sake of safety, could you try and remember the Android version of the affected devices?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot remember exactly, but it must have been 2.2 and/or 2.3.