# NinePatchDrawable constructor ignores padding?

Tags: android, nine-patch

I am trying to construct a *NinePatchDrawable* at run-time from a **compiled** nine-patch PNG file located in the assets the folder. The problem is that the constructor seems to ignore the padding in the nine-patch chunk.

```
InputStream inStream = context.getAssets().open(imagePath);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream);
byte[] chunk = bitmap.getNinePatchChunk();
boolean isNinePatch = NinePatch.isNinePatchChunk(chunk);
Rect padding = new Rect();
if(isNinePatch)
    drawable = new NinePatchDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap, chunk, padding, imagePath);
```

This code returns a *NinePatchDrawable* with zero padding on all sides. I am positive the PNG file contains the correct padding margins because the following code returns a *NinePatchDrawable* with the right padding, using the exact same compiled nine-patch PNG file:

```
InputStream inStream = context.getAssets().open(imagePath);
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromResourceStream(context, null, inStream, null);
```

(Why don't I just use this method instead? [Because it crashes on some handsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747089/exception-in-drawable-createfromresourcestream-htc-only).)

If anyone can show me how to construct a NinePatchDrawable at run-time *with the correct padding* I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: You can refer to the solution here, it work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065996/ninepatchdrawable-does-not-get-padding-from-chunk